# Script to get the code from github on my azure VM

Tags: azure, github, virtual-machine

I want to write a script in Azure VM which will checkout the code from my github repository and and copys the code to my Azure VM C: drive.

Could you please throw some lights on it about what could be the approach for this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? What have you done so far?

Comment: How do you normally pull code from your github repo? I would think you'd do the same thing from an Azure VM that you'd do on your local dev machine, no? You should edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

So far we download the code and by RDC we add the code to VM drive.

What I want to do that, I want to write a script which will copy the code from my github repository to my windows virtual machine drive.

I have not much idea about how to go with this. What could be the possible approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at the Custom Script Extension for Azure.  You can get started at this blog: [Custom Script Extension](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/11/vm-agent-and-extensions-part-1/)

The basics will be to:

1. Write a powershell script that pulls from your github repo (this may help get you started [Powershell GitHub Download](http://ramblings.narrabilis.com/windows/powershell-download-file))
2. Upload powershell script to Azure Blob Store
3. Set-AzureVMCustomScriptExtension on your VM and Update-AzureVM

   ```
   Get-AzureVM -Name $name -ServiceName $servicename | Set-AzureVMCustomScriptExtension -StorageAccountName $storageaccount -StorageAccountKey $storagekey -ContainerName $container -FileName 'file1.ps1','file2.ps1' -Run 'file.ps1' | Update-AzureVM
   ```

Other than the script contents mentioned in 1. above, this is a good walk-through: [Custom Script Extension Example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-extensions-customscript/)

The other option would be to use the Azure Powershell Desired State Configuration extension, but it may be overkill for what you're looking for:
[Azure Powershell DSC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2014/08/07/introducing-the-azure-powershell-dsc-desired-state-configuration-extension.aspx)